# Using Fragments for ViewPager in Android

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Can anyone tell me why this isnt working?  I havent changed this file since it worked last but now I get the error below:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v13.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private final static int NUM_PAGES = 2;
private ViewPager mPager;
private ScreenSlidePagerAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

// Instantiate a ViewPager and a PagerAdapter.
mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
mAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
mPager.setCurrentItem(2);
}

private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int i) {

    Fragment frag = null;

    switch (i) {
    case 0:
        frag = new PageOneFragment();
        break;
    case 1:
        frag = new PageTwoFragment();
        break;

    }
    return frag;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return NUM_PAGES;
}
}
}
```

The error is on "frag = new PageTwoFragment();" which states "Type mismatch: cannot convert from PageTwoFragment to Fragment".

Maybe I should create two projects from now on, last good version and then current working project.  Is this something other people do?

Thanks

Comment: about creating two projects, instead use version control, such as github or bitbucket

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Problem is, that you are mixing Android Fragments how there were introduced in API11 and Fragments from android support library.

You have to use one or the other, but not both.

Change your imports to

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v13.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
```

And change `getFragmentManager()` to `getSupportFragmentManager()`.

And it will work using the support lib.

Calling `mPager.setCurrentItem(2);` with a pager of 2 Fragments crashs, though.
Only `0` and `1` are valid values in your case.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but it still isnt working working.  When I change my imports to match these I get this "The constructor FragmentStatePagerAdapter(FragmentManager) is undefined", this "The return type is incompatible with FragmentStatePagerAdapter.getItem(int)" and this "Type mismatch: cannot convert from PageOneFragment to Fragment".  If I change them all to "support.v4" then I only get the following error "Type mismatch: cannot convert from PageOneFragment to Fragment".  Any ideas?

Comment: I have changed the "mPager.setCurrentItem(2);" to "mPager.setCurrentItem(1);" though, thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Hey, you were right about imports, I checked my other classes and I somehow changed the imports on those too, I have now changed the imports on my other classes and this has fixed the issue.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Based on the depth of the answer I have accepted this.  Thanks to the other answer too though, everyone's input on this was really helpful.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You imported the wrong Fragment.

You need to **import android.support.v4.Fragment**

Furthermore, your adapter only handles 2 Fragments. Therefore calling

```
ViewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
```

will cause problems, since the index for the first fragment is 0.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but it still isnt working working. When I change my imports to match these I get this "The constructor FragmentStatePagerAdapter(FragmentManager) is undefined", this "The return type is incompatible with FragmentStatePagerAdapter.getItem(int)" and this "Type mismatch: cannot convert from PageOneFragment to Fragment". If I change them all to "support.v4" then I only get the following error "Type mismatch: cannot convert from PageOneFragment to Fragment". Any ideas?

Comment: I have changed the "mPager.setCurrentItem(2);" to "mPager.setCurrentItem(1);" though, thanks for pointing this out

Comment: Hey, you were right about imports, I checked my other classes and I somehow changed the imports on those too, I have now changed the imports on my other classes and this has fixed the issue.  Thanks for your help.